# Writing mp3 to file/$_FILES indexing

Tags: php

I am sending an mp3 blob to an upload.php script and I want to write it to an mp3 file:

```
<?php    

    // allow CORs
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: enctype");


    $data = $_FILES['data'];
    $filename = $_FILES['data']['name'];

    // write the data out to the file
    $fp = fopen($filename, "wb");

    fwrite($fp, $data);
    fclose($fp);


?>
```

This writes a .mp3 file with the correct name (as sent from the other location), but the mp3 is 0KB. Am I accessing the data incorrectly?

If I print $_FILES I get this:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [name] => 1589403398963.mp3
            [type] => audio/mpeg-3
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpupE5ji
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 32751
        )

)
```

Comment: What you need is `move_uploaded_file`.

Comment: I don't understand how that would solve the problem.

Comment: Because it is the function specifically written to do exactly what you are trying to do, which is why it is named what it is. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: I did this, and it creates a file this time with xKB, but it doesn't appear to be a valid mp3? 
$filename = $_FILES['data']['name'];
 $file = $_FILES['data']['tmp_name'];

 move_uploaded_file($file,$filename);